# Calling C++ function from JavaScript script running in a web browser control

Tags: javascript, c++, windows, com, iwebbrowser2

I have embedded a web browser control in my c++ application. I want javascript running in the web browser control to be able to call a c++ function/method.

I have found mentions of three ways to do this:

1. Implement an ActiveX component that acts as a middle man. (Implementation details here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicd/archive/2007/04/18/calling-into-your-bho-from-a-client-script.aspx)
2. Use window.external. (Also discussed in the link above, but no implementation provided)
3. Add a custom object to the window object

I want to go with the third option, but I haven't found any working examples on how to do that. Can someone please show me how to do it, or link to a working example on the net somewhere.

The closest to an example that I have found is the first reply by Igor Tandetnik in [a thread in the webbrowser_ctl news group](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.webbrowser_ctl/browse_frm/thread/afb353de46bae2f8). But I'm afraid I need more help than that.

I'm embedding an IWebBrowser2 control and I am not using MFC, ATL or WTL.

**EDIT:**

Going by the pseudo-code given by Igor in the thread I linked earlier, and code found in the codeproject article "[Creating JavaScript arrays and other objects from C++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/javascriptfromcpp.aspx?display=PrintAll)" I've produced some code.

```
void WebForm::AddCustomObject(IDispatch *custObj, std::string name)
{
    IHTMLDocument2 *doc = GetDoc();
    IHTMLWindow2 *win = NULL;
    doc->get_parentWindow(&win);

    if (win == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    IDispatchEx *winEx;
    win->QueryInterface(&winEx);

    if (winEx == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    int lenW = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, name.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
    BSTR objName = SysAllocStringLen(0, lenW);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, name.c_str(), -1, objName, lenW);

    DISPID dispid; 
    HRESULT hr = winEx->GetDispID(objName, fdexNameEnsure, &dispid);

    SysFreeString(objName);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return;
    }

    DISPID namedArgs[] = {DISPID_PROPERTYPUT};
    DISPPARAMS params;
    params.rgvarg = new VARIANT[1];
    params.rgvarg[0].pdispVal = custObj;
    params.rgvarg[0].vt = VT_DISPATCH;
    params.rgdispidNamedArgs = namedArgs;
    params.cArgs = 1;
    params.cNamedArgs = 1;

    hr = winEx->InvokeEx(dispid, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, &params, NULL, NULL, NULL); 

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return;
    }
}
```

The code above runs all the way through, so everything looks alright that far.

I call AddCustomObject when I receive the DISPID_NAVIGATECOMPLETE2 DWebBrowserEvents2 event passing this as `*custObj`:

```
class JSObject : public IDispatch {
private:
    long ref;

public:
    // IUnknown
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv);
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef();
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release();

    // IDispatch
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoCount(UINT *pctinfo);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfo(UINT iTInfo, LCID lcid,
        ITypeInfo **ppTInfo);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetIDsOfNames(REFIID riid,
        LPOLESTR *rgszNames, UINT cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID *rgDispId);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid,
        LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS *Params, VARIANT *pVarResult,
        EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo, UINT *puArgErr);
};
```

Noteworthy implementations might be

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE JSObject::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
    *ppv = NULL;

    if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_IDispatch) {
        *ppv = static_cast<IDispatch*>(this);
    }

    if (*ppv != NULL) {
        AddRef();
        return S_OK;
    }

    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}
```

and

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE JSObject::Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid,
    LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS *Params, VARIANT *pVarResult,
    EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo, UINT *puArgErr)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Invoke", "JSObject", MB_OK);
    return DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND;
}
```

Unfortunately I never get the "Invoke" message box when I try to use the "JSObject" object from the javascript code.

```
JSObject.randomFunctionName();  // This should give me the c++ "Invoke" message
                                // box, but it doesn't
```

**EDIT 2:**

I implemented `GetIDsOfNames` like so:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE JSObject::GetIDsOfNames(REFIID riid,
    LPOLESTR *rgszNames, UINT cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID *rgDispId)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    for (UINT i = 0; i < cNames; i++) {
        std::map<std::wstring, DISPID>::iterator iter = idMap.find(rgszNames[i]);
        if (iter != idMap.end()) {
            rgDispId[i] = iter->second;
        } else {
            rgDispId[i] = DISPID_UNKNOWN;
            hr = DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME;
        }
    }

    return hr;
}
```

and this is my constructor

```
JSObject::JSObject() : ref(0)
{
    idMap.insert(std::make_pair(L"execute", DISPID_USER_EXECUTE));
    idMap.insert(std::make_pair(L"writefile", DISPID_USER_WRITEFILE));
    idMap.insert(std::make_pair(L"readfile", DISPID_USER_READFILE));
}
```

with the DISPID_USER_* constants defined as private class members

```
class JSObject : public IDispatch {
private:
    static const DISPID DISPID_USER_EXECUTE = DISPID_VALUE + 1;
    static const DISPID DISPID_USER_WRITEFILE = DISPID_VALUE + 2;
    static const DISPID DISPID_USER_READFILE = DISPID_VALUE + 3;

    // ...
};
```

**EDIT 3, 4 and 5:**

Moved to [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754268/returning-string-to-javascript-from-c-function)

**EDIT 6:**

Made [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754268/returning-string-to-javascript-from-c-function) out of the "returning a string" edits. That way I can accept [Georg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168225/georg-fritzsche) reply as that answers the original question.

**EDIT 7:**

I have gotten a few requests for a fully working, self contained, example implementation. Here it is: https://github.com/Tobbe/CppIEEmbed. Please fork and improve if you can :)

Comment: Does `GetIDsOfNames()` return something sensible?

Comment: @Georg: No, it doesn't. It just returns E_FAIL.

Comment: I'm now running in a similar problem as you were... considering that you've managed do accomplish this would you consider making an working example available for download somewhere?

Comment: You are not the first wanting a small self contained example. I will make one when I have the time (probably several months from now). In the meantime you can look at this, as that is where I'm using this code: https://github.com/tobbe/lsactivedesktop

Comment: @titel: Here's a small self contained example: https://github.com/Tobbe/CppIEEmbed

Comment: @Tobbe, i have downloaded CppIEEmbed sample and i could compile it, but how to call c++ function(syntax of calling c++ function) from Java script(i don't know Java script). please can u give me sample java script code.

Comment: @Tobbe, I downloaded the sample also and can't find the http://localhost/lionwiki to open, can you provide the lionwiki?

Comment: Just change the URL. Doesn't have to be lionwiki, it can be anything :)

Comment: @Tobbe , if I am not misunderstood then the sample is showing us how to call C++ function from javascript? Supposedly the javascript in html is vital part right?

Comment: No, the CppIEEmbed just shows how to embed a web page. If you want to see how to call a C++ function you'll need to look at the code in https://github.com/Tobbe/lsactivedesktop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement `GetIDsOfNames()` to do something sensible as that function will be called by client code before `Invoke()`.
If you have your interfaces in a type library see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221434.aspx) for an example. If you want to use late-binding instead, you can use [`DISPID`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221242.aspx) greater `DISPID_VALUE` and less than `0x80010000` (all values `<= 0` and in the range `0x80010000` through `0x8001FFFF` are reserved):

```
HRESULT GetIDsOfNames(REFIID riid, LPOLESTR *rgszNames, UINT cNames, 
                      LCID lcid, DISPID *rgDispId)
{
    HR hr = S_OK;
    for (UINT i=0; i<cNames; ++i) {
        if (validName(rgszNames)) {
            rgDispId[i] = dispIdForName(rgszNames);
        } else {
            rgDispId[i] = DISPID_UNKNOWN;
            hr = DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME;
        }
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, 
               DISPPARAMS *Params, VARIANT *pVarResult, EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo, 
               UINT *puArgErr)
{
    if (wFlags & DISPATCH_METHOD) {
       // handle according to DISPID ...
    }

    // ...
```

Note that the `DISPID`s are not supposed to change suddenly, so e.g. a static `map` or constant values should be used.

Comment: That example, and other examples I've found, make use of the DispGetIDsOfNames function that needs an "ITypeInfo" pointer. What is this ITypeInfo thing, and how do I create/get one I can use in my case?

Comment: The IDs (DISPID) I return in GetIDsOfNames, are they only used in Invoke()? Or are they used in more places. What I really want to know is if I can just make them up myself, or if I have to use something like GetDispID to generate them for me. (Using made up/random IDs seems to work, but I just want to know if doing that is a bad idea or not)