# Call C# BHO method from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer, com, bho

I need to call a C# BHO method from javascript

I have followed the solution given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287961/calling-c-sharp-bho-methods-from-javascript/11614528#11614528)

I get the error:

```
'mshtml.HTMLWindow2Class' does not contain a definition for 'myExtension'.
```

I cannot assign:

```
dynamic window = browser.Document.parentWindow;
```

as parentWindow is undefined, I have to cast to (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2) and (mshtml.IHTMLWindow2)

Does anyone have a full working example I could refer to or any help or alternative solutions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've the same problem. And the following fix seems work in my BHO:

```
dynamic window = _webBrowser.Document.parentWindow;
var windowEx = (IExpando)window;
PropertyInfo p = windowEx.AddProperty("myExtension");
p.SetValue(windowEx, this);
```

instead of:

```
dynamic window = _webBrowser.Document.parentWindow;
var windowEx = (IExpando)window;
PropertyInfo p = windowEx.AddProperty("myExtension");
window.myExtension = this;
```

Comment: Super useful, taught me something and saved me an hour of time :) If you're ever back in SO - reply to this comment and I'll award you a bounty for this answer. Short note - in .NET <4.5 it's `p.SetValue(windowEx, this,null);`

Comment: On another note: the _webBrowser object needs to be an instance of 'IWebBrowser' not 'IWebBrowser2'