# BHO exposing javascript method works in IE 9+ but fails in earlier versions

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-8, bho

I'm making a BHO that exposes method to JavaScript.

It works okey in IE 9 and IE 10, but fails in IE 8 with **RuntimeBinderException**: `"mshtml.HTMLWindow2Class" does not contain "signJson"`.

Code is mostly based on [live reload IE extention](https://github.com/dvdotsenko/livereload_ie_extension).

Here is a way that function is injected into window:

```
    public void InjectScriptResource(dynamic window)
    {
        var windowEx = (IExpando)window;

        if (windowEx.GetProperty("signJson", BindingFlags.Default) == null)
        {
            windowEx.AddProperty("signJson");
            window.signJson = this;
        }
    }
```

What's different about about `mshtml.HTMLWindow2Class` in IE 8 from IE 9? What is a proper way to inject method into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615753/call-c-sharp-bho-method-from-javascript) on Stack Overflow. You just have to change code to this:

```
public void InjectScriptResource(dynamic window)
{
    var windowEx = (IExpando)window;

    if (windowEx.GetProperty("signJson", BindingFlags.Default) == null)
    {
        // windowEx.AddProperty("signJson");
        PropertyInfo p = windowEx.AddProperty("signJson");
        // window.signJson = this;
        p.SetValue(windowEx, this);
    }
}
```