# IE BHO DWebBrowserEvents2_Event.BeforeScriptExecute don't have webbrower.Document on page Refresh

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer-11, bho

I am writing a BHO for IE11. In the BHO I have exposed some methods using IExtension interface to be called by the JavaScript.
The Code is below

```
    IWebBrowser2 _webBrowser2;
    
    int IObjectWithSite.SetSite(object site)
    {
    try
    {
    _site = site;
    
        if (site != null)
        {
            var serviceProv = (IServiceProvider)_site;
            var guidIWebBrowserApp = Marshal.GenerateGuidForType(typeof(IWebBrowserApp));
            var guidIWebBrowser2 = Marshal.GenerateGuidForType(typeof(IWebBrowser2));
    
            IntPtr intPtr;
            serviceProv.QueryService(ref guidIWebBrowserApp, ref guidIWebBrowser2, out intPtr);
    
            _webBrowser2 = (IWebBrowser2)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(intPtr);
    
            ((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)_webBrowser2).BeforeScriptExecute += S2_BeforeScriptExecute;
        }
        else
        {
            ((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)_webBrowser2).BeforeScriptExecute -= S2_BeforeScriptExecute;
            _webBrowser2 = null;
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
    
    private void S2_BeforeScriptExecute(object pDispWindow)
    {
        dynamic window = _webBrowser2.Document.parentWindow;
        IExpando windowEx = (IExpando)window;
        windowEx.AddProperty("myExtension");
        window.myExtension = this;
    }
```

In this everything is working fine except that when user clicks on refresh button in IE,
_webBrowser2.Document.parentWindow gives exception

```
System.NotSupportedException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
   at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject )
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at BHO.S2_BeforeScriptExecute(Object pDispWindow)
```

Also I have tried instance of SHDocVw.WebBrowser instead of IWebBrowser2, but still the same issue.

So is there any alternative to this or something else that works fine?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it contains the parentWindow property, I forget to convent the Document to HTMLDocument, so, it doesn't show the parentWindow property on my sample. I have deleted my previous reply. Since, I'm still not find the real reason, can you try to add an if condition to check whether the Document is null before getting the parent window. Like this: `if(webBrowser.Document != null) { dynamic window = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)webbrowser.Document).parentWindow;`. Besides, you could try to use the DocumentComplete event, instead of BeforeScriptExecute event.

Comment: I have checked through debugging, Document is not null, parentWindow is.

Comment: Also about using DocumentComplete, IE doesn't fire it on pressing refresh button.

Comment: Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068872/calling-c-sharp-bho-methods-from-javascript-still-not-working), if the site is not null, it is better to add the  BeforeScriptExecute event, then, if the site is null, remove the event. code like this:`if(site != null){ webBrowser = (IWebBrowser2)site;((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)webBrowser).BeforeScriptExecute += S2_BeforeScriptExecute;} else { ((DWebBrowserEvents2_Event)webBrowser).BeforeScriptExecute -= S2_BeforeScriptExecute;  webBrowser = null;  }`

Comment: I am doing the same as you have suggested, also I have followed the link you specified but the issue still exists.