# 2 way communication between WebControl and Win32/MFC

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am working on a win32/MFC application; in this application I have embedded WebControl on dialog.

when application is launched then it will load web page, in that user will enter some fields and then press submit button.

Once user presses the submit, then server will process that data and displays some unique ID to user.

Now our requirement is, we don’t want to display that unique ID on the web page instead, that web page needs to send that data to our client application(Win32/MFC).

To do this I found a solution:

[Calling C++ function from JavaScript script running in a web browser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747414/calling-c-function-from-javascript-script-running-in-a-web-browser-control)

is this is the right way to do it or is there any other solution is there.

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override [OnGetExternal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bat7a958%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (or if you host in your own window, [change your IDocHostUIHandler::GetExternal implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#GetExternal)) and return a pointer to a CComTarget that has an appsubmit method [exposed via automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w7a36sdf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Change the web page to add an [onsubmit handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that calls your method with the value of a hidden field

```
return window.external.appsubmit(uniqueId);
```